# 503 error code for Springboot container connecting to mongo container using docker-compose

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect my spring-boot application(REST endpoints) running in a Tomcat container with a mongo container. I am using docker-compose to link both the containers. The application was working perfectly fine. It just stopped working suddenly.

Following is my code:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.13
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
#COPY pom.xml .
#RUN ["mvn", "clean", "install"]
COPY /target/TestProfileManager.war .
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
 app:
  container_name: VF-BACKEND
  restart: always
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8083:8080" #VF Webservice
  depends_on:
   - mongo
  links:
   - mongo
 mongo:
  container_name: VF-MONGO
  image: mongo:4.0.2
  ports:
   - "27018:27017"
  volumes:
   - /data/vfdb:/data/db
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo:27018/tsp
```

If I run the application from the IDE as a standalone application, the endpoints do return the response. Only during container communication, I am getting 503. I could not find any post that answers my question.

Thanks for the help. Since, the code was working before, not pasting the classes. Let me know if I should share them as well.

Comment: Container-to-container communication always uses whatever port the server process is actually listening on; it ignores `ports:` and doesn't know about the remapping.  Try changing to the default MongoDB port 27017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `mongodb://mongo:27017`, in service to service communication you do not need to use publish port.

> It is important to note the distinction between `HOST_PORT` and
>   `CONTAINER_PORT`. the HOST_PORT is `27018` and the container port is
>   `27017` . **Networked service-to-service communication use the
>   CONTAINER_PORT**

[compose-networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)